# python 2.7 imaplib error

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I tried to connect to my mail server via imaplib and got an error in constructor:
My code:

```
import imaplib
imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('my_host.com', 1234)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/username/www/site/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py in __init__(self, host, port, keyfile, certfile)
   1163             self.keyfile = keyfile
   1164             self.certfile = certfile
-> 1165             IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
   1166 
   1167 

/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py in __init__(self, host, port)
    197             self.state = 'NONAUTH'
    198         else:
--> 199             raise self.error(self.welcome)
    200 
    201         typ, dat = self.capability()

error: None
```

Python recieved response from server and then raise an error, but it's a normal continuation response.
Response from server:

```
+OK my_host.com POP3 MDaemon 12.5.6 ready <MDAEMON-F201406061147.AA472534MD1387@my_host.com>
```

What I should do to recieve my mails from my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demon point that he using protocol POP3. You are trying to communicate whit him using IMAP protocol. Change lib to poplib or change port to communicate via IMAP protocol(default is 143).